# Programmatically triggering a D3 brush event

Tags: javascript, d3.js, event-handling

I have seen examples [here](https://bl.ocks.org/micahstubbs/3cda05ca68cba260cb81) and [here](http://bl.ocks.org/timelyportfolio/5c136de85de1c2abb6fc) were a brush is triggered in JavaScript. I want to understand the implementation of the [first](https://bl.ocks.org/micahstubbs/3cda05ca68cba260cb81) one.

**Background**

The [first example](https://bl.ocks.org/micahstubbs/3cda05ca68cba260cb81) bundles two D3 line charts in a single svg container; classes `focus` and `context`, respectively:

[image: Stubbs brush example]

The `context` chart (marked in light blue, above) is the one containing the brush, which can be triggered by a mouse click:

[image]

When we look inside its group container, we find the designated brush parameters; under the `extent` class:

[image]

**Question 1.**

I don't understand what happens in the last two lines, *in particular the last line*:

```js
function drawBrush(a, b) {
      // define our brush extent

      // note that x0 and x1 refer to the lower and upper bound of the brush extent
      // while x2 refers to the scale for the second x-axis, for context or brush area.
      // unfortunate variable naming :-/
      var x0 = x2.invert(a*width)
      var x1 = x2.invert(b*width)
      console.log("x0", x0)
      console.log("x1", x1)
      brush.extent([x0, x1])

      // now draw the brush to match our extent
      // use transition to slow it down so we can see what is happening
      // set transition duration to 0 to draw right away
      brush(d3.select(".brush").transition().duration(500));

      // now fire the brushstart, brushmove, and brushend events
      // set transition the delay and duration to 0 to draw right away
      brush.event(d3.select(".brush").transition().delay(10duration(500))
}
```

In `brush(d3.select(".brush").transition().duration(500));`, the current brush parameters are selected with a transition precondition; which is passed to `brush`, so it can draw the new brush according to the changed `brush.extend` values.

In `brush.event(d3.select(".brush").transition().delay(10duration(500))`, it seems that the previous line sets the parameters, after which `brush.event` *executes* with the new brush parameters. Can someone make sense of this? How do the [brush events](https://github.com/d3/d3-brush#brush-events) apply to this case?

**Question 2.**

I also don't see how exactly, this event action gets linked back to the `focus`ed chart. If find the mechanisms via callbacks quite cryptic:

```js
var brush = d3.svg.brush()
      .x(x2)
      .on("brush", brushed);
```

This snippet seems crystal-clear: *the* brush is made and linked to the `brush` event listener. On a brush event, brushed will act as the event handler. Furthermore, the scale of `context`'s x-axis `x2` is passed to the brush, as it sits on the `context` chart.

But I'm not quite sure how `brushed` works:

```js
  function brushed() {
    x.domain(brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent());
    focus.select(".area").attr("d", area);
    focus.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
  }
```

Just to be sure, is it correct that a new axis is generated in `focus.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);` with the `brush` parameters set in `x.domain(brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent());`?

Answer (score 1):

First, there is a typo in the last line. In the code it actually is:

```
brush.event(d3.select(".brush").transition().delay(1000).duration(500))
```

Back to your question, the confusion you're facing trying to understand what the [brush events](https://github.com/d3/d3-brush#brush-events) have to do with it is quite simple: you're reading the **D3 v4 docs**, while that code uses **D3 v3**.

This is [brush.event](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/SVG-Controls.md#brush_event) in D3 v3:

> brush.event(*selection*)
>
> If selection is a selection, it dispatches a brush gesture to registered listeners as a three event sequence: brushstart, brush and brushend. This can be useful in triggering listeners **after setting the brush extent programatically**. (emphasis mine)

As you can clearly see, the first line changes the brush itself (the *context*), while the second one changes the big area chart (the *focus*).

Comment: Well, what's the purpose of the `brushstart` and `brushend` events? As I understand it, *brush* events are fired at each new tick in case the selection is a transition; *brush* gets dispatched over the course of the transition*. Is it just, so as we have a means to *mark* the start and end of a brush transition? I guess it has something to do with enabling the use of setting the brush extent programmatically, but I don't see how the `brushstart` and `brushend` *enable* anything.